# create circular image border without fix width and height

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image like so:

[image]

i want to show just green area and overflow hidden
:

[image]

Exactly like image blow:

[image]

**the problem is image display like so:**

[image]

**The image in the html file (not background image);**

Here is the html file:

```
<div class="thumb">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="/image/25085">
   </div>
```

CSS file :

```
.jbTourItem img {
    width: 100px;
    border: 4px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: @RickBronger read the question again please

Comment: Ok. Deleted my answer. How many times you going to change your question? Then i know when to answer ;).

Comment: @RickBronger i just edited for clear what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henrik already answered this answer will also assume you can set the height of the wrapping div but in this example flexbox is used so that you can get the image totally centered inside the circle.

```css
.thumb {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.thumb img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <img src="http://i.cbc.ca/1.2101005.1382019145!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_620/hotel-room.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Original image</h4>
  <img src="http://i.cbc.ca/1.2101005.1382019145!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_620/hotel-room.jpg" />
</div>
```

[Flexbox browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to specify the width and height of your image, but know what size of the circle you want, I use to do like this.

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 118px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 118px;
}

.center {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
}

.thumb {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">
    <div class="center">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nByPB.jpg" class="thumb">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) CSS property:

```
.img-responsive {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: check the question again

Comment: @Radian are image dimentions are static or dynamic? Can you hardcoded image width or height?

Comment: when you set `width` and `height` it will show up like the way you want.

Comment: @RickBronger the images are relative height, i want overlape a div over images (on the center of images) and hidden overflows

Comment: the width is fixed but height is auto @RickBronger

Comment: @Radian can you move this inside `backround-image`? For example inline as `style="background-image..."`?

Comment: i can do this , but i looking for another solution without `background-image `@antyrat

Comment: @Radian I don't think this is possible. Or this will require very ugly hacks or JS.

Comment: @Radian: to clarify: you have images that always have the same width? Or do you make them the same width with css? (`width: 100px`)?

Comment: same width with css(width: 100px) @niemaszoka